# Angular v5.2.4, Http interceptor: Error: Uncaught (in promise)

Tags: angular

After a long search I keep getting the same answer that this seems to be correct:

```
  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): 
  Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(request).catch(errorResponse => {
      const status = errorResponse.status;
      if (status === 401) { this.matDialog.open(UserDialogComponent); }

      return Observable.throw(status);
    });
  }
```

This however gives the following error:

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): 401
>       at S (polyfills.8847e333380b2b4c3385.bundle.js:1)
>       ...

Besides the:

> polyfills.8847e333380b2b4c3385.bundle.js:1 GET
>   http://localhost:8080/users/auth 401 (Unauthorized)

error.

The 401 is intentional to test my error handling.

Is this the expected and only handling of Http errors with interceptors in Angular, or can I catch this error somehow?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone still interested in the answer:

Turns out it was a route guard somewhere else in the project that did not .catch the subscription.

So this is not normal behavior and should be investigate further.

Comment: The problem for was that I had in my cache old data, because of having multiple credentials tests on the same localhost for different projects.